# Can't call with javascript appended class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't call the class which is appended with javascript in jquery. It just doesn't respond to it at all.

I append the html with this:

```
$(function () {
var $scntDiv = $('#parts');
var i = $('#parts input').size();

$('#addField').on('click', function () {
    var part = '<div id="parts' + i + '"><hr /><input type="text" id="auto_part' + i + '" class="auto_part" name="auto_part' + i + '" placeholder="Dio" /><br/>' +
        '<textarea type="text" id="auto_description' + i + '" class="auto_description" name="auto_description' + i + '" placeholder="Vise informacija"></textarea> <br />' +
        '<a href="#" class="addPhoto' + i + '" style="display:block;">Add Photo</a><input type="file" name="auto_image" class="auto_image' + i + '" style="display:none;" /><a href="#" class="removefield">Izbrisi dio</a></div>';
    $scntDiv.after(part);
    $("#row_count").val(i);
    i++;
    return false;
});

$(document).on("click", ".removefield", function () {
    if (i > 2) {
        $("#row_count").val(i);
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        i--;
    }
    return false;
});
```

});

So it creates addPhoto2, addPhoto3 and so on. But when I use this:

```
$(function () {
    $(".addPhoto2").click(function(){
       console.log("Hello");
    });
});
```

It just doesnt do anything with addPhoto2. While I can call addPhoto itself which is loaded as default.

Comment: Don't create inline HTML or you'll get mad - google for **client side templating**.

Comment: i++, can you do that so early?  Does size() equate to being a number or a string initially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach the event to the element when it is created because a simple event will not work if the element is not present in the DOM when you try to wire that event up. You could use event delegation for this. However, you already have a good hook in place.

What you will want to do is attach this event after the element is placed here:

```
$scntDiv.after(part);
$('.addPhoto' + i).click(function(){
    alert("!"); 
 });
```

Here is a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eQbEt/

Comment: Thanks a lot this one helped! :D